# Loss of DP signal when other devices get connected

Tags: graphics-card, linux-mint, lenovo-laptop, external-display, displayport

I have a Dell U2415 connected to my Lenovo ThinkPad T460p as an external monitor via Mini DisplayPort, and I encounter the following issue: when I connect, for example, an external hard disk via USB or headphones to the audio jack, the external monitor might go, or goes, black. Sometimes the signal comes back, other times it doesn't and the monitor goes into power save mode.

I am asking myself the following:

- Is this a hardware or a software related issue?
- Either way, how can it be solved?

To describe the situation in more detail, please find below a list of information that could be relevant:

- The OS I am running is Linux Mint 18.3 Cinammon 64-bit
- The laptop I am using has both an internal graphics card (Intel HD Graphics 530) and a dedicated graphics card (NVIDIA GeForce 940MX, 2GB)
- I am using the nvidia-384 drivers (`384.130-0ubuntu0.16.04.1`)
- The GPU can be switched using the NVIDIA X Server Settings
- The behavior I have described occurs when using the dedicated graphics card
- The internal graphics card doesn't work at all with the external monitor (i.e., the monitor stays black at all times)

What is interesting is that I've recently had my mainboard replaced (for a different reason, that is). The issue already occurred regularly with the old mainboard. With the new mainboard, the issue has certainly not improved and even feels worse. Still, to me, the fact that it happend irrespective of the mainboard in use lets a software issue seem more plausible to me.

Comment: not sure if this can help you, but I had a similar issue with ubuntu on my Dell XPS laptop (equipped with an nvidia discrete GPU):
when my external monitor fails to wake up from sleep, I am able to recover by switching to console mode (with CONTROL-ALT-F2): both the laptop screen and the external monitor enter console mode showing the login request in the command-line user interface. After a few seconds  I can return to the graphical login screen (with CONTROL-ALT-F1) and both screens work normally

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a grounding issue, due to the fact it happens when things get plugged in.

However, to find out if it is a software issue, I would try booting another OS.  You can try another Linux live image.  However, I would recommend booting a Windows install image.  If it is a software issue, it might be endemic to Linux itself and be present in every distribution.  If the issue continues to happen in Windows, it is most likely a hardware issue.

Comment: I've updated the graphics driver in the meantime and regarding USB ports, it seems stable now. In fact, the only time the monitor goes black is when I plug a *specific* set of headphones into the audio jack. I've tried it with other headphones and the signal is stable. Does this still (or maybe even more so now) sound like a grounding issue to you? To rule out software issues, I will try booting a different OS and I'll also use a different cable that connects my laptop to the monitor.

Comment: @foobar can't say with certainty. It could be these specific headphones are made wrong causing an issue, possibly with ground. It could just be bad connection inside. Keep testing.

Comment: I've exchanged the DP cable and the problem seems to be gone. I am however a bit  worried that the audio cable of the headphones can have such an effect, that is, video signal loss when getting connected. Is it safe to use these headphones still with regard to my mainboard?